# Why am I getting "Failed to load ApplicationContext" Spring, jUnit with JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, junit

Why am I getting "Failed to load ApplicationContext" Spring, jUnit with JavaConfig

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HelloWorldConfig.class)
public class TestApp
{

    @Test
    public void testBean()
    {
      ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);

      HelloWorld helloWorld = context.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
      helloWorld.setMessage("I am in Staten Island, New York");

      Assert.assertEquals(helloWorld.getMessage(), "I am in Staten Island, New York");
    }
}
```

here is the stack trace.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext  at
org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)     at
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)   at
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)     at
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)   at
com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at
com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at
com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'messageService': Injection of autowired
dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
autowire field: private
com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.dao.MessageDao
com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.service.MessageServiceImpl.messageDao;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type
[com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.dao.MessageDao] found for
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at
org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 28 more Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
autowire field: private
com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.dao.MessageDao
com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.service.MessageServiceImpl.messageDao;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type
[com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.dao.MessageDao] found for
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 44 more Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type
[com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.dao.MessageDao] found for
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace in order to find the culprit of this error.

Answer (score 16):

The stack trace shows the problem

The log message says that you haven't defined MessageDAO:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.johnathanmarksmith.hellospring.dao.MessageDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This bean is autowired in MessageServiceImpl which is defined in HelloConfig.class but is not in your config class

Furthermore, when using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class you have no need to create the ApplicationContext in your test, just Autowire HelloWorld into your JUnit

Comment: Also helpful for a newb to Spring and Java, like myself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/884640

Comment: Sir, I stumbled upon this answer after ~ 2Hrs of debugging. Thanks a lot for pointing out this error in the `stack trace`. I can sleep peacefully now. : D